# Rename Index Error parameter @objname is ambiguous

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I tried to rename index using this query

```
EXEC sp_rename
  N'[Test].[Documents].[tmp_rg_xx_UQ__Tmp_Docu__704721A403F0984C]',
  N'UQ__Tmp_Docu__704721A403F0984C',
  N'INDEX'
```

It gives me the below error

> Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (INDEX) is wrong.

Comment: So presumably you don't have an index of that name then.

Comment: I have index with this name

Comment: Script out the "Create Table" including indexes and the entire script you are running and add it to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the database name from the sp_rename - It only works on current db

```
USE test
GO
EXEC sp_rename
  N'[Documents].[tmp_rg_xx_UQ__Tmp_Docu__704721A403F0984C]',
  N'UQ__Tmp_Docu__704721A403F0984C',
  N'INDEX'
```

Comment: That is a schema name not a database name.